# how to get data from html form in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to do a simple login form in html and get the response in an alert but i can't do it.
this is my html code

```
<form id="myForm" action="/verifica.js" method="post">
```

in a js file i do the submit request

```
var subs = document.getElementById("myForm");
subs.submit();
```

in another js file there is the get request

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "login.js"); 
xhr.onload = function(event){ 
    alert("The server responded with: " + event.target.response); 
}; 
var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("myForm")); 
xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: What actually happens? Nothing? Wrong data? Errors loading the page?

Comment: error loading page

Comment: And that error would be....? You should be giving us all the information you possibly can instead of just saying "here is broken code".

Comment: your "action" should be a server or html page, not a JS

Comment: ok, what should i do with an html page? i don't have a server

Comment: You need a server, if you want server authentication. If you don't want a server you can do client side authentication, but it is really insecure and noone recommends it.

Comment: Your alert message states `"The server responded with: " + event.target.response)`. How could the server respond anything if you don't have a server...

Comment: @EmilianoMontesdeoca if there is no server, what do you want to secure exactly?

Comment: @Kaiido i was simulating, i know there isn't a server lol

Comment: Yes but even your code is trying to talk to a server, so why don't you have one? Search how to run a localhost on your OS and do your page from there.

Comment: you can't bind a JS to an "action", you should use an URL, it can be the same page "#" or anything like "/send-request"

Comment: `xhr.open("GET", "login.js");` will get you the textual content of the "login.js" file, will not do any action.

Answer (score 1):

The way you tried to do this is wrong, the action property is used to redirect the user to the given link.

Instead, catch the submit event and prevent the submit default action.

You can then use the FormData class to retrieve the form data.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="username" >
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>

<script>
    document.querySelector('#myForm').addEventListener('submit', e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = new FormData(e.target);

        alert(data.get('username'));
    });
</script>
```

Then you will be able to send the result asynchronously to a remote server in order to check credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I use the event `submit` to handle form submission in js.

```
let myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function()
{
    //Your submit logic with data sending goes here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

An ["action"](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) can't be a JS file. It should be an URL that will process the submit request. Or it can be the same page...

If you cant to perform some validations before the page submit, you can use the following code (here the [codepen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/wYMRLL?editors=1011)):

```js
let myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

let mySubmit = function() {
  let tel = document.getElementById("tel").value;
    var parsed = parseInt(tel);
  if (isNaN(parsed)) {
    alert("wrong number!!!");
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("success!!!");
    return true;
  }
};
```

```html
<form id="myForm" action="#" onsubmit="mySubmit()">
  <input type="text" id="tel" placeholder="tel">
  <button type="submit">verifica</button>
</form>
```